# Updated nested subdocuments in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, subdocument

I am trying to update nested subdocument in mongodb,

```
  {
id: 100, 
     status: [ { 

                 campaigns: [ 
                    { timestamp: "2014-07-30", 
                      task: [
                                { 
                                  id: "1",
                                  created: "2014-07-30"
                                } 

                        ]
                    }, 
                    { timestamp: "2014-07-31", 
                      task: [
                                { 
                                  id: "2",
                                  created: "2014-07-31" // need to update this field
                                } 

                        ]
                    }, 
                ]
            }, 
        ]

    }
```

Update Query

```
db.collectionname.update({"id": 100,"status.campaigns.task.id":"2"},{$set:{"status.0.campaigns.$.task.created:"2014-08-01"}});
```

the above query updates only first record (task.id = "1" created date) its not updating task.id="2" subdocument!!!!

Comment: Why are you using `status.0`? Do you need to update only the first entry in `status` array?

Comment: problem in campaings positional param not status array

Comment: You **can** update the task if you want, but you need to know its position within the arrays. Do you know that beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

> **Nested Arrays**
>   The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value

Check the [mongoDB docs on positional operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

So have you have three nested arrays `status`,`campaigns`,`task`. The positional operator will not work.

My guess is that the innermost position(innermost array) is stored in `$`. That's why you are getting `$`  as `0`.

Follow the [JIRA trackable](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831) for this issue if you are interested and vote for it.

Comment: For your current schema you can't do it in a single update query. A rethink of your schema might help. This is a known issu and a [JIRA Trackable](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831)

Comment: I need to do this in yiimongoDBsuite in php

Comment: It doesn't matter. MongoDB doesn't support positional operator for nested array. You should consider changing your schema.

Comment: Can you suggest any schema design for above example ?

Comment: It isn't so simple. You need to consider a whole lot of factors like queries, read frequency, write frequency and stuff like that to design a good schema. [This site](http://dba.stackexchange.com) is more appropriate for stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

You **can** update the subdocument, but you need to know its position within the various nested arrays that you have in your document structure. This could be the case if say, you followed a specific numbering scheme for the `id` field of the subdocuments you insert into your nested arrays.

If that is a viable strategy for you, your `update()` would not require the second key/value pair in the first argument, because you are simply looking for the document containing the subdocument that you want to update and the `_id` field is unique. For the second argument, you would then use the indexes you would have for the position of the subdocument within the nested arrays.

For the example document you post, where you are updating the `created` field in the **first** element of the `task` array in the **second** element of the `campaign` array in the **first** element of the `status` array, then you do something as follows:

```
db.collection.update({ "_id": 100}, { $set: { "status.0.campaigns.1.task.0.created" : "2014-08-01" }});
```

If, however, you do not know the position of the subdocument you want to update, then you will not be able to update it. This is due to the fact that, as explained in the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/), "the positional operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array".